# Marking navigation button as active using CSS

Tags: html, css, vue-router

I have square navigation buttons where I want to visually show which are active, for example using:

[image: Example]

At the moment I use `background: linear-gradient` for this purpose. This however is hard to animate and I therefore am looking for alternatives. The HTML structures looks like:

```
<div class='navigation-button'>
    <div class='navigation-button-container'>
        <i class='fa fa-bars'></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

with corresponding CSS:

```
.navigation-button {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: purple;
}

.navigation-button-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center; 
}

.navigation-button-container i {
    margin-top: 25%;
    margin-bottom: 25%;
    color: white;
}

.active {
    background: linear-gradient(right, blue 0%, blue 10%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 10%);
}
```

The `active` class can be applied to the `navigation-button-container` to get the desired effect. I want to however fade this in and out and as I understand `linear-gradients` cannot be animated.

I have looked in adding a  element before the `navigation-button-container` and animate it's width and using the CSS ::before syntax but neither seemed to be of help. Is there an efficient CSS way to get the desired effect using `@keyframes` or `transition`?

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly you want to animate your button, is it solid colour -> gradient? If so, you could place an element (or a `::before`) behind the button which will have  the `linear-gradient` background, then fade it using `opacity`.

Comment: Excuse me, I want to animate the width of blue from left to right. A slide-in to say.

Comment: Oh, okay, … If the element is on the edge of the window you could use a `::before` element and actually slide it from off-screen?

Comment: It is at the moment not an element but a background color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you needed? There is a `::before` pseudo-element on `.nb-container` which has a width transition.

```css
.nb {
  background-color: #f00;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.nb-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center; 
}

.nb-container i {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 25% 0 25%;
}

.nb-container ::before {
  background-color: #00f;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: width .2s;
  width: 0;
}

.nb-container:hover ::before, .nb-container:focus ::before {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
Mouse over the elements to see the effect:
<div class="nb">
  <div class="nb-container">
    <i class="fa fa-bars">∆</i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="nb">
  <div class="nb-container">
    <i class="fa fa-bars">®</i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="nb">
  <div class="nb-container">
    <i class="fa fa-bars">©</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `::before` element is very versatile in the way it can be animated. So if you wanted a fade-in instead of a slide-in:

```css
.nb {
  background-color: #f00;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.nb-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center; 
}

.nb-container i {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 25% 0 25%;
}

.nb-container ::before {
  background-color: #00f;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  width: 20%;
}

.nb-container:hover ::before, .nb-container:focus ::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
Mouse over the elements to see the effect:
<div class="nb">
  <div class="nb-container">
    <i class="fa fa-bars">∆</i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="nb">
  <div class="nb-container">
    <i class="fa fa-bars">®</i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="nb">
  <div class="nb-container">
    <i class="fa fa-bars">©</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can see the animation working but for some reason my <i> tags have a width of 0px when using ::before, what could be the cause of that?

Comment: Are you sure it is caused by `::before`? There might be some problems with using font Awesome, so I don't recommend applying pseudo-element styles directly to `.fa` elements – I think (I'm not sure) font Awesome uses pseudo-elements to actually display its icons. Additionally, in the example above, I applied `display: inline-block` to the `i` element, which you most likely should not need with `.fa` …

Comment: I checked and it indeed works when using regular content inside the `<i>` tag (or e.g. &#xf0c9;), removing `display: inline-block`. But the ::before isn't applied directly to the `i` tag right?

Comment: No, the `::before` in my example is applied to `.nb-container`.